# how to connect a MySql database from Windows Xp to linux ..?

Tags: java, mysql

i am working in Windows Xp platform and i want to access a another computer database so that database is a mysql and that computer is working on Linux platform ..so problem is i cant not connect with this different two OS (XP to LINUX) ... so please give me some solution...

Comment: The OS of the server is completely irrelevant. Are you facing any specific problem?

Comment: what is error message while you try to connect ?

Comment: Your problem is not related to operating systems. It may be about the connection parameters of the database, maybe typo?

Comment: you need to provide the correct port number, correct host, ensure privileges is granted, ensure network is connected, and also check the firewall

Comment: How do you try to connect? What did you do and try? What failed? What are your implications, how do you think it works? As the previous commenter said, OSes are completely irrelevant. You just connect to mysqls open port and that’s it.

Comment: @jimit  plz.. follow all above comments .. these are good comment...and can u connect MySql locally....?

Comment: @ajreal covered almost everything ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java it goes like this. Use your own IP, port, database name, userId and password. MySQL default port is 3306 but it may be a little safer to use another port that is not so well known.

```
try {
 linuxCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://191.91.9.19:5900/linuxdb?user=loginID&password=myPassword&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
 linuxStmt = linuxCon.createStatement();
} catch ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Java will not care about the OS when connecting to a MySQL server. You simply need to pass the correct connection URL. You'll need to provide more details about how you connect (configuration) and also check that your Linux server accepts connections from outside (firewall/MySQL configuration).